# How to avoid "Can only update a mounted or mounting component" warning?

Tags: reactjs

I keep getting the following error when trying to update setState in my SignUp component:

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting
>   component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the SignUp
>   component.

The error occurs just after a user has signed up, when calling `this.setState({ signedUp: true });` inside the open method. Why is `this` "unmounted" at this particular moment and how can I avoid this issue?

```
 export default class Signup extends Component {
       constructor(props) {
          super(props);

          this.state = {
            isLoading: false,
            email: "",
            password: "",
            signedUp: false,
            isVerified: false
          };

       this.open = this.open.bind(this)
    }

    open() {
      if (this.state.signedUp===false)  {
        this.setState({ signedUp: true });
      }
    }

    close() {
      console.log('in close')
    }

    handleChange = event => {
      this.setState({
        [event.target.id]: event.target.value
      });
    }

    handleSubmit = async event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.signup(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((user) => {
        this.open()
      }, (error) => {
        alert(error)
      });
    }

    signup(email, password) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function onSuccess(user) {
          if (user) {
            user.updateProfile({
              displayName: (firstName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + firstName.slice(1) + ' ' + lastName)
            }).then(function() {
              resolve(user);
            }, function(error) {
              alert(error)
            });
          } else {
              reject('User not signed up');
          } 
        })
      });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="Signup">
          <Grid>
            <Row>
              <Col sm={8} smOffset={2} md={6} mdOffset={3} lg={4} lgOffset={4}>
              <h1 className="text-center font-size-l">Sign up</h1>
              <Panel>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                  <FormGroup controlId="email" bsSize="large">
                    <ControlLabel>Email</ControlLabel>
                    <FormControl
                      type="email"
                      placeholder="you@company.com" 
                      value={this.state.email}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                  </FormGroup>

                  <FormGroup controlId="password" bsSize="large">
                    <ControlLabel>Password</ControlLabel>
                    <FormControl
                      value={this.state.password}
                      placeholder="Enter a secure password" 
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                      type="password"
                    />
                  </FormGroup>

                  <LoaderButton
                    block
                    className="btn-primary"
                    bsSize="large"
                    type="submit"
                    isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
                    text="Next"
                    loadingText="Signing up…"
                  />
                </form>
              </Panel>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Grid>

        <Modal show={this.state.signedUp} onHide={this.close} >
          <Modal.Body>
          <p>Check your inbox for further instructions.</p>
          <LoaderButton
            className="btn-primary"
            bsSize="large"
            type="submit"
            text="Resend email"
          />
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
       </div>
       );
       }
    }
```

Comment: Add a `componentWillUnmount` event handler, and see if it hits by adding a logging call or a `debugger` breakpoint, it could be you are updating the state on an unmounted component. Also note that a `submit` will refresh the page, are you sure you want to use submit, maybe you could send the submit call using `fetch` instead

Comment: @Icepickle just tried that and the component indeed unmounts when the sign-up form is submitted. So the question rephrased a bit: How can I avoid a component incl. a form being unmounted after submit?

Comment: Don't use `submit`, use an `onClick` event instead, or use `return false` from the `this.handleSubmit` method (however, as it is marked as `async`, I doubt it will work, as async methods send a promise back, i'm very curious why it is marked as `async` though, I don't see any reason for it from the code that you have shown us) and to be completely honest, I don't even see why it would be necessary for you to use a `submit` event, you are handling everything through firebase, are you sure you want to submit the data as well?